# Sql Server 2012 - manage to login with sa and then fail to login with sa

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a Windows server 2012 with SQL Server 2012, running on AWS
I have configured the sa user, and I manage to login with it

But, once in a while, I can not login anymore with sa and then I have login with windows authentication reset the sa password, and then everything works fine.

Did anyone encounter that before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try e.g.:

```
CREATE LOGIN YourLogin WITH PASSWORD='yourpass'
```

Alter login with:

```
ALTER LOGIN sa WITH PASSWORD='yourpass', CHECK_POLICY=OFF
GO
ALTER LOGIN sa ENABLE
GO
```

The CHECK_POLICY=OFF parameter makes the login immune to domain setup changes. Now login with sa

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have the 'Enforce password expiration' checkbox ticked on the settings page for the SA user. This will cause it to use the Windows password policy which may have a timeout.

See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lcris/archive/2008/02/20/sql-server-password-policy-faq.aspx

Comment: No, Nither 'Enforce password policy' nor 'Enforce password expiration' is checked

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing this same thing with my server on an AWS instance. I think the culprit may have been an overly simple sa password (I was using "sa"). I went into the management studio and checked "enforce password policy", unchecked "enforce password expiration, and set a password complex enough to meet the policy...and now it has been up all night without hitting that problem, knock on wood.